# CSRF token invalid in load balanced symfony2 application

Tags: mysql, session, symfony, load-balancing

I have inherited a symfony2 project which in the live environment runs in over 2 load balanced servers.  The session is stored in the mysql database that the application uses for this reason.

The issue i am having is that on forms that have CSRF protection sometimes the token is coming back not valid.  I am guessing this is because the server that generated the token isn't always the server that gets the form POST and can't match the token being sent.

I am very, very new to symfony and have tried a few different solutions to generate the token using the session and SessionCsrfProvider from the Symfony framework.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or has had a similar problem?

Comment: Does the session work as expected otherwise?

Comment: Yes the session management for users works fine.  It is just the csrf token warning that is set off if the form is posted back to the server that it didn't originate from.  I have tested this by just working on one of the load balanced servers using the IP address.

Comment: What i am struggling with is understanding if the SessionCsrfProvider is using the session stored in the database or not.  Any tips on debugging?  it is tricky to test as the only load balanced environment we have is live.  Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that the secret key in parameter.ini is the same on both servers?  The only time I had trouble was when I changed the key in an already deployed application.  I suppose you could make your own SessionCsrfProvider and do some logging (server host, user ip address, session id) to try and track things down.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the keys weren't the same for some reason, i corrected this and restarted apache and the issue is still present.

Comment: Make sure you close the browser and possibly clear the session cookie to ensure new session ids for the client.

Answer (score 2):

The CsrfProviders will generate tokens by concatenating secret key (from parameters.ini) + intention (defaults to null) + **the session id**.

By default, symfony is configured to use the `SessionCsrfProvider`, which uses the session **storage** id.

If you are using the PDOSessionStorage or NativeSessionStorage object, it will return the `session_id()`.

It could mean your `session_id()` is not the same depending on what machine handles the request.

Comment: It seems the fix was that the parameters.ini secret key wasn't the same across both servers and even when i corrected this it didn't take effect until i had cleared the app cache and restarted apache on both servers a few times.  Thanks for all your help.